# Instance accessible by instances it creates

Tags: java

I want to create a non-static class that can have it's instance accessed by the instances it creates, for example:

```
public class Foo {
    private String name;

    public Foo(String name) {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.getFooName();
        this.name = name;
    )

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}


public class Bar {
    String getFooName() {
        return Foo.toString(); //How do I get the Foo that created it?
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo("Steve");
        new Foo("Bob");
    }
}
```

If I made Foo.name static, all instances would have the same name. I could pass the instance of Foo as a variable when creating a Bar, but that would get messy, supposing bar made more objects which also wanted to access the Foo. It there some way to allow Bar and all the objects it creates to access the instance of Foo that created them?

Edit: The context of this is a non-static primary class that creates instances of many different classes. Each instance needs to be able to find the other instances created by the primary instance that created it, when multiple instances of the primary class may exist

Comment: In general, an object shouldn't know or care who - or what - created it.  If it *NEEDS* to know ... then your best bet is to pass a reference to `this` in the child object's constructor, so the child can reference its creator as needed.

Comment: There is no such thing as an implicit reference to a Foo that created a Bar. You need to have an explicit referecne somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `Foo` reference to the `Bar` constructor:

```
public class Foo
{
    String name;
    public Foo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        Bar bar = new Bar(this);   
    }
    public String getName () {
        return this.name;
    }
}

public class Bar 
{
    Foo creator;

    public Bar (Foo creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    String getFooName() {
        return creator.getName();
    }
}
```

Though, I'm not sure what's the point of creating a `Bar` instance in the `Foo` constructor without keeping a reference to it.

Another option is to make `Bar` an inner class of `Foo`:

```
public class Foo
{
    String name;
    public Foo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        Bar bar = new Bar();
    }
    public String getName () {
        return this.name;
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public Bar () {
        }
        String getFooName() {
            return getName();
        }
    }
}
```

This way each `Bar` instance will be associated with an enclosing instance of `Foo`.

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid, since that approach would require passing the Foo reference to everything Bar creates that wants to access it

Comment: @ARandomPerson623462 You could avoid passing a reference if you make Bar an inner class of Foo

Comment: If Bar and every class it used were inner variables it would end up with the entire project in one file

Comment: @ARandomPerson623462 well, those are the two options (I'm aware of) for a Bar instance to have access to the Foo instance that created it.

Comment: @ARandomPerson623462  - if you already coded a million places where you create an object ... and now decide the object needs to know who created it - then there's probably a design flaw, and you probably need to refactor your code anyway.  BEST CASE: If you can avoid needing to know who created the object - great.  BEST SOLUTION: If the child really needs this info, then you should pass a reference in the constructor.  Period.